# What is the magnetic Field Strength in the plane of and outside a current loop?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I am trying to find a relationship between the magnitude of the magnetic field at distance $x$ in the plane of a wire loop with radius $R$, $n$ turns and a current of $I$ passing through it. $x$ is in one dimension, **outside** and normal to the loop.

I'm assuming that the entire coil can be treated as one loop of $nI$, and have been trying to use the Biot-Savart law in the form
$$B=\frac{\mu_0nI}{4\pi}\frac{1}{[d(x,\theta)]^2}\sin{\theta} \ dL$$
where $d(x,\theta)$ is the distance from any point on the loop to the point $x$ distance from the loop in terms of $x$ and $\theta$. From examples of this law being applied in other situations, I know that because $L$ changed $\theta$, I need to express $dL$ in terms of $d\theta$ and then evaluate the integral from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=2\pi$.

Geometrically, using the law of cosines, I came to (this may be incorrect)
$$d(x,\theta)=\sqrt{2R^2+2xR+2R(x+R)\sin{\theta}+x^2}$$
which brings the entire equation to
$$B=\frac{\mu_0nI}{4\pi}\frac{1}{2R^2+2xR+2R(x+R)\sin{\theta}+x^2} \ dL$$
I have not had much luck with $d\theta$. The closest I got was
$$L=R\arcsin{\left({-\frac{\cos{\theta}\sqrt{2R^2+2xR+2R(x+R)\sin{\theta}+x^2}}{R+x}}\right)}$$
Differentiating this gives a horribly complicated function which would probably be impossible to integrate.

We tested this experimentally, and got the results
[image]

Am I applying the law incorrectly or making a mistake? Is there an easy answer to this, or is it too complicated to quantify? I haven't been able to find anything online about this whatsoever, which is concerning. That, alongside how quickly complicated the maths becomes makes me think there isn't an easy answer to this at all.

Sorry if I didn't explain this very clearly.

Comment: I think that Grant Trebbin answers your question? http://www.grant-trebbin.com/2012/04/off-axis-magnetic-field-of-circular.html

Comment: How can 'x' be in the plane of the loop and normal to the plane?

Comment: I have done similar calculations for selected points within the field of a Helmholtz coil, using numeric integration on a computer.  You start with cross products and then work with components.

Answer (score 0):

I think your sin theta is off because it is based on the cross product of $r \times dl$. It should be the angle between your point at x and the dl, and is not the same as theta.

I have graphed it here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l2gmgbzo4q
Note, my r is your x and my b is your R. Also, my B field is was measured in the opposite direction.

To analytically solve it though would require elliptic integrals.

Answer (score 0):

B outside the loop can be found using the magnetic scalar potential:
\begin{eqnarray}
B_\theta(r,\theta) & = &-\frac{2\pi I}{c}\sum_{{\rm odd}\; l}^\infty
\left(\begin{array}{c} -\frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{l+1}{2}\end{array}\right)
\frac{a^{l+1}P_l^1(\cos\, \theta)}{r^{l+2}}.
\end{eqnarray}
This can be summed on a computer.

Answer (score 0):

I know from Section 10.6 of Zangwill (i.e., pg 324-5), that the magnetic vector potential in cylindrical coordinates for a filamentary ring of current coaxial with the $z$ axis, that is  centered at the origin, whose radius is $ a$, and whose current density is in the $\hat{\boldsymbol{\varphi}}$ is given by
$$
\mathbf{A}(\rho,z) = \hat{\boldsymbol{\varphi}}\,\frac{1}{2}\,\mu_0\,I\,a \int\limits_{k=0}^\infty     J_1(k\,\rho)\, J_1(k\,a)\,\exp^{-k\left|z \right|}\,   dk.
$$
The variable $J_1$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order 1.

Since $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}) = \boldsymbol{\nabla}\times \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r})$,
magnetic field in cylindrical coordinates for a filamentarty ring of current coaxial with the $z$ axis, whose  centered at the origin, whose radius is $ a$, and whose current density is in the $\hat{\boldsymbol{\varphi}}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}) 
&= 
-
\frac{\partial \left[ \frac{1}{2}\,\mu_0\,I\,a \int\limits_{k=0}^\infty     J_1(k\,\rho)\, J_1(k\,a)\,\exp^{-k\left|z \right|}   \,   dk\right]}{\partial z}
\,
\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}
\\
&+
\frac{1}{\rho}\,
\frac{\partial \left(\rho\, \frac{1}{2}\,\mu_0\,I\,a  \int\limits_{k=0}^\infty     J_1(k\,\rho)\, J_1(k\,a)\,\exp^{-k\left|z \right|}\,   dk\right)}{\partial \rho}
\,
 \hat{\mathbf{z}}\,.
\end{align*}
Your question only asks for the field in the plane coincident with the ring with $N$ turns. Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\boxed{
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{B}(\rho,\varphi,0) 
&= 
 \frac{\mu_0\,N\,I\,a}{2\,\rho}    \int\limits_{k=0}^\infty     J_1(k\,\rho)\, J_1(k\,a)\,   dk 
\,
 \hat{\mathbf{z}}
\\
&+
  \frac{\mu_0\,N\,I\,a   }{2} \int\limits_{k=0}^\infty    \frac{\partial  J_1(k\,\rho)}{\partial \rho}\, J_1(k\,a)\,   dk 
\,
 \hat{\mathbf{z}}\,.
\end{aligned}
}
\end{equation}
Maybe one can go a little further, but this is good enough for me.